# Seleccionar items en un checkBoxList c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Tengo un problema al seleccionar los items marcados en mi CheckBoxList, ya que cuando recorro el CheckBoxList este no identifica cuales están con un valor de true.

```
CheckBoxList cx = new CheckBoxList();
int cont = 0;
            cx = cbxServicios;
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
            {
                if (cx.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    cont = cont + 1;
                    Mensaje(Convert.ToString(cont));
                    
                }
            }
```

en este caso mensaje solo es un ejemplo de algo que quiero que se repita cada vez que encuentra un valor que este chekeado en el CheckBoxList.

Al correr el codigo el if solo pasa de todos los cx.Items[i].Selected y nunca entra en el if...

Nota mi CheckBoxList lo lleno de forma dinamica en otra parte del codigo, esto funciona perfecta mente y tambien puedo sacar el valor con un .value de cada item, pero no puedo saber si este esta checkeado o no.

Comment: ¿Para qué instancias `CheckBoxList` si luego reemplazas la referencia por otra? Mejor asigna directamente el objeto que quieres `CheckBoxList cx = cbxServicios`. Puedes verificar si `cx` es `null` y evitas entrar al for.

Comment: Si y no, ya que mi error no se originaba en el CheckBoxList, sino que era en el PostBack, ya que en mi load Page cargo mi CheckBoxList de manera dinámica, y cada vez que cliqueo el botón para recorrer el for se limpiaban los valores.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi! yo lleno mi check list de forma dinamica, es agregar este if en la parte donde se llenan los checks

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
//Aqui se llena de manera dinamica el CheckBoxList
}
```

para que no se llenen de nuevo cuando se llama el botón

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).